# File "<stdin>", line 1 syntax error in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/Andrew/Documents/GitHub/Digital-solutions-assignment/Movie booking system.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/Andrew/Documents/GitHub/Digital-solutions-assignment/Movie booking system.py"
    ^
```

Whenever I try to run this code it gives this error and I have no idea on how to fix it.

Edit: someone asked for code where errors

```
#Imports and Database connection--------------------------------------

import sqlite3

from tkinter import Menu

from unittest import result #importing the code for using sql lite

conn = sqlite3.connect('Moviebookingsystem.db') #this string will depend on 

where the database is compared to this file

cur = conn.cursor() #create cursor to database
```

Comment: You are sitting at a Python prompt (">>>") trying to execute a shell command.  You need to be in a terminal window in order to execute the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs without problems. Follow [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to get started with python in VS Code.

[image]

In VS Code, you can run the code using the options outlined in red in the picture. Or use the right mouse button on the code and select the same option. Or customize shortcut keys to run code.

Answer (score 0):

The comment with 5 upvotes was the correct answer.

You are sitting at a Python prompt (">>>") trying to execute a shell command.
You need to be in a terminal window in order to execute the script itself.

So type exit() to get out of the Python prompt. This will solve your error.